# Plotar figuras 3D para dados em lista

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Tenho uma lista `a` com três matrizes e um vetor `v` com três frequências (reais positivos quaisquer), estas matrizes formam triângulos através de uma função que criei `pplot`. Eu desejo adicionar a informação do vetor `v` para construir prismas, ou seja, sair do 2D para o 3D. Alguém tem alguma ideia ou dica de como fazer?

Abaixo segue a função `pplot` e um toy problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
pplot <- function(polygon){
  polygon <- lapply(polygon, function(x) {colnames(x) <- NULL; x})
  vertex_number = nrow(polygon[[1]])
  g = ggplot2::ggplot()
  names(polygon) = 1:length(polygon)
  k <- plyr::ldply(polygon, function(x) data.frame(x))
  g <- ggplot2::ggplot(k, ggplot2::aes(x = X1, y = X2, group = .id)) + ggplot2::geom_polygon(colour = "black", fill = NA)
  return(g)
}

a <- list()
b1 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b2 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b3 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)

a[[1]] <- b1
a[[2]] <- b2
a[[3]] <- b3

v <- c(.3, .5, .1)
#Para exemplificar a funcao que eh 2D
pplot(a)
```

Obs.: Obrigatoriamente os dados são listas.

## Resposta desejada

Por exemplo, formando um prisma através de `b1` e `v[1]`, então a base do prisma é `b1` e altura (h) é `v[1]`. O mesmo raciocínio segue para `b2` com `v[2]` e `b3` com `v[3]`.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Assim que tiver mais tempo vou tentar. Acho que uma boa saída é usar o plotly.

Comment: Obrigado @DanielFalbel, vou tentando aqui, se eu conseguir uma boa resposta eu posto aqui. Abs.

Comment: Eu não consegui visualizar a resposta desejada. Os elementos `a[[1]]`, `a[[2]]` e `a[[3]]` da lista `a` são as coordenadas das faces do prisma? Este prisma é, obrigatoriamente, um tetraedro? Para que serve o vetor `v`, já que ele parece não fazer diferença alguma? O que significa dizer que este vetor `v` vai fazer "sair do 2D para o 3D"?

Comment: `a[[1]]` é a base de um prisma e `v[1]` é a altura, `a[[2]]` é a base e `v[2]` é a altura de outro prisma. Gostaria que estes três prismas fossem plotados no mesmo gráfico (sobrepostos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caros, baseado na resposta que obtive em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614888/plot-3d-prisms-using-ggplot2-and-plotly/41433697#41433697
Adaptei o método para plotar um prisma de base poligonal com qualquer quantidade de lados.

```
library(rgl)
a <- list()
b1 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b2 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b3 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)

a[[1]] <- b1
a[[2]] <- b2
a[[3]] <- b3

v <- c(.3, .5, .1) #Altura

pprism <- function(a, h){
  # general loop to plot every prism
  for(i in 1:length(h)){
    # transform matrizes to data.frames and add height column 
    # -> separation of top and bottom triangle
    sides <- nrow(a[[1]]) - 1 
    top <- data.frame(a[[i]], h[i]) 
    bottom <- data.frame(a[[i]], 0) 
    # adjust colnames to axis names
    colnames(top) <- c("x", "y", "z") 
    colnames(bottom) <- c("x", "y", "z") 
    # plot triangles (as wireframes)
    lines3d(bottom, front = "line", back = "line")
    lines3d(top, front = "line", back = "line")
    # plot vertical lines to connect the triangles
    for(i in 0:sides){
      segments3d(
        x = c(bottom$x[1+i], top$x[1+i]),
        y = c(bottom$y[1+i], top$y[1+i]),
        z = c(bottom$z[1+i], top$z[1+i])
      )
    }
  }
  #### add coordinate system ####
  axes3d()
}
pprism(a,v)
```